# How to deal with the problem of such an error?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Why am I getting an error?

How do I build a file for this error?

I'm trying to understand and can't, what's wrong here? Or how do I create a file with its parameters? Or how do I know what the parameters should be in this file?

I would love to help!

I would love to help!!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZduTz.png)

```
package com.vtweens.components.website.server_requests.register
{

 import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONDecoder;
 import com.vtweens.consts.ITEM;
 import com.vtweens.dataobjects.item.ImageItemNoCache;
 import com.vtweens.shell.ServerConfig;
 import com.vtweens.util.Log;
 import com.vtweens.util.Map;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
 import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
 import flash.net.URLVariables;

 public class GetRegistrationItemsRequest extends EventDispatcher
 {
  
  private static var itemsBoy:Map = new Map();
  
  private static var itemsGirl:Map = new Map();
  
  private static const MAX_RETRIES = 2;
   
  
  private var serverConfig:ServerConfig;
  
  private var secure;
  
  private var gender;
  
  private var retries = 0;
  
  public function GetRegistrationItemsRequest(param1:ServerConfig, param2:Boolean)
  {
     super();
     this.serverConfig = param1;
     this.secure = param2;
  }
  
  public static function getItemImage(param1:Object, param2:String = ".") : Sprite
  {
     if(param1)
     {
        return new ImageItemNoCache(param1[ITEM.TYPE],param1[ITEM.ORDINAL],param1[ITEM.ID],param1[ITEM.INVENTORY_TYPE],null,null,param2);
     }
     return new Sprite();
  }
  
  public function sendRequest(param1:int) : void
  {
     var _loc2_:URLVariables = null;
     this.gender = param1;
     if(param1 == 1 && itemsBoy.size() > 0 || param1 == 2 && itemsGirl.size() > 0)
     {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
     }
     else
     {
        _loc2_ = new URLVariables();
        _loc2_.gender = param1;
        this.sendInqueryRequest(_loc2_,this.onRequestResponse,this.onRequestError);
     }
  }
  
  private function onRequestError(param1:IOErrorEvent) : void
  {
     param1.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.onRequestResponse);
     param1.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,this.onRequestError);
     Log.error("AllProductsRequest: onRequestError error:" + param1.text);
     if(this.retries < MAX_RETRIES)
     {
        ++this.retries;
        Log.error("AllProductsRequest: Retying (" + this.retries + ")");
        this.sendRequest(this.gender);
     }
     else
     {
        dispatchEvent(new IOErrorEvent(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR));
     }
  }
  
  private function onRequestResponse(param1:Event) : void
  {
     var _loc3_:* = undefined;
     var _loc4_:Object = null;
     param1.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.onRequestResponse);
     param1.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,this.onRequestError);
     var _loc2_:Array = new JSONDecoder(param1.target.data).getValue();
     for each(_loc3_ in _loc2_)
     {
        _loc4_ = new JSONDecoder(_loc3_).getValue();
        if(this.gender == 1)
        {
           itemsBoy.put(int(_loc4_[ITEM.ID]),_loc4_);
        }
        else
        {
           itemsGirl.put(int(_loc4_[ITEM.ID]),_loc4_);
        }
     }
     dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
  }
  
  public function get itemsMap() : Map
  {
     if(this.gender == 1)
     {
        return itemsBoy;
     }
     return itemsGirl;
  }
  
  public function getItemsObjByType(param1:int) : Array
  {
     var _loc4_:* = undefined;
     var _loc2_:Array = [];
     var _loc3_:* = this.gender == 1 ? itemsBoy.getValues() : itemsGirl.getValues();
     for each(_loc4_ in _loc3_)
     {
        if(int(_loc4_[ITEM.TYPE]) == param1)
        {
           _loc2_.push(_loc4_);
        }
     }
     return _loc2_.sortOn(ITEM.ORDINAL,Array.NUMERIC);
  }
  
  private function sendInqueryRequest(param1:URLVariables, param2:*, param3:*) : *
  {
     var _loc4_:URLRequest = null;
     var _loc5_:URLLoader = null;
     (_loc4_ = new URLRequest(this.serverConfig.getRegistrationItemsUrl(this.secure))).contentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
     _loc4_.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
     _loc4_.data = param1;
     (_loc5_ = new URLLoader()).addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,param2);
     _loc5_.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,param3);
     _loc5_.load(_loc4_);
  }
```

}
}

Comment: This is a de-compiled script. While de-compilation might seem to be a handy tool, it does not, by any means, guarantee the exact replica of the source code, or a working-as-intended code, or a working code, or a compile-able code, or even a readable one. Even less, if the original author didn't want anyone to.

Comment: How to make it work?

Comment: Analyze it, understand what the code is supposed to do, then compose your own script, readable, working, the one you can control.

Comment: It's a game that's already ready, it just needs to be completed with some files that are missing like this example, how do I build it?  can you help  to guide?

Comment: Why are you working with the de-compiled code then, instead of working with the original (readable, compile-able, working) source?

Comment: It's an old game and it's closed, I can't work with the original

Comment: I don't have the source, the code belongs to an old game that was closed...